# How can I catch an event of an Object inside a ComboBox?

Tags: vb.net, events, combobox

So basically I have a ComboBox on a form, which I populated by adding custom object named "Category" and by setting the DisplayMember to the property "Name" of my object.

On another form that can be opened at the same time, I can edit the name of theses "Category" objects. I raise an Event, "NameChanged" but how can I catch it on the form which contains the ComboBox ?

Even if the property "Name" of the object "Category" change, the display on the ComboBox doesn't autoupdate. So I need to catch the event, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your Category class implement INotifyPropertyChanged, you can handle events when a property changes.

To do so, you have to change your property from a simple property:

```
// will NOT raise event
public string Name { get; set; }
```

to something more like:

```
// will raise event
public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set
    {
        if (_Name != value)
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
}
private string _Name;
```

and then implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your class as well:

```
    public event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Now, when adding a Category object to your ComboBox, subscribe to the PropertyChanged event which will be raised every time the Name property changes.

**An Even Better Way**

Consider using the [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) class to populate your ComboBox.  Binding automagically uses INotifyPropertyChanged to update the display when a property value changes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am now trying to recode my combobox with databindings.

Comment: I can't do it. Do I have to use the ComboBox.DataBindings.Add method ? If yes, how to use it cuz I tried many ways and I can't make it work. My data source is a class which inherits a List(of Category).

Comment: Most of my experience with data binding is in WPF and Silverlight.  Some good places to start with WinForms and binding are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654/winforms-databinding-and-foreign-key-relationships and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454959/winforms-databinding